# Ошибка XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

В консоли выходит такая ошибка:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'javascript:;' from origin
>   'https://teamtimeofficial.info' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Из-за этой ошибки не работает регистрация (в базу данных новые данные не добавляются) на сайте https://teamtimeofficial.info.
Вот сам скрипт регистрации, все данные отправляются в определённый файл.

```
$('#reg_btn').click(function(){
var oferta = $('#reg_rules').prop('checked');
var login = $('#reg_login').val();
var pass = $('#reg_pass').val();
var mail = $('#reg_email').val();
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/actions/reg.php',
data: {'oferta': oferta, 'login': login, 'pass': pass, 'mail': mail, 'token': '<?php echo $token; ?>'},
cache: false,
success: function(result){
if (result == 'offer') {
$.jGrowl('Вы не согласились с правилами', { theme: 'growl-error' });
}
if (result == 'regged') {
$.jGrowl('Данный логин уже зарегистрирован', { theme: 'growl-error' });
}
```

и так далее...

Как можно исправить эту проблему, что бы регистрация работала?

Comment: Сервер должен высылать в заголовке CORS ваше доменное имя, как разрешённое.

Comment: @ArchDemon а как это сделать? Что бы сервер высылал моё доменное имя как разрешённое?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648542/how-to-use-a-relative-path-for-jquery-ajax-url

Comment: @СашаАндреев это ваш сервер?

Comment: Для начала, как Вы запускаете этот скрипт? Оно ругается даже не на заголовки CORS еще, а на то, что скрипт не загружен по http (или по какому-то другому из перечисленных там протоколов)

Comment: Не нужно задавать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз. Лучше было отредактировать исходный вопрос.